# Delta Lake Vaccum

Tags: delta-lake

In Delta Lake, is it possible to only vaccum specific rows from the data. Client has a requirement to vaccum the data of a customer, when customer is deactivated in an effort to delete customer's entire data set. They do not want to keep history.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete customer's data, and then run vacuum to remove old files that contained original customer data.

Comment: I am already deleting the customer's data. How do I vaccum only those files which had original customer data. Vaccum does not have a where precidate to delete based on a table column.

Comment: You run vacuum globally - it will identify what files aren't referenced anymore, and delete them (by default, after 7 days)